# Split on first column

Tags: awk, split

I'm trying to split a coverage file (tab delim) on first column, so that each chromosome has a specific file.

I've already done with

```
cat  file.coverage | awk ' { if ($1 == "chrn"){print}}'
```

but in this way I've to do n-times for n-samples.

I'd like to have this in a recursive way: read the first column, while the chr is the same, print it out in a file `A`, otherwise print in a file `B` and so on.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Give an example of your input and expected output.

Comment: ... what about `awk '{ print >> $1".log" }' file.coverage` ? (Side note no need to cat and pipe, just let awk read the file itself.)

Comment: " I've to do n-times for n-samples" - please use plain English.  We don't know what is "do n-times for n-samples".  Meanwhile, -1 for the question.

Comment: thanks @Tensibai exactly this!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Tensibai indicated in the comments, you can do-

```
awk '{print >> $1".log"}' file.coverage
```

Explanation-

The `awk` one liner simply appends lines into files that are named according to the indices in the first column.

You don't need to `cat filename | awk`. `awk` is capable of reading files on its own. That's a useless usage of `cat`.

On another side note (for future codes that you write), your initial line could be shortened to-

```
awk '$1 == "chrn"' file.coverage
```

No need for the `if`.

Comment: `>` is enough, it will append.